# Drupal 8 Rest API

Tags: drupal-8

My Custom API's are working fine, I've deployed code on staging Server but I'am getting below error.

Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "" plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for Drupal\rest\Plugin\Type\ResourcePluginManager are: dblog, file:upload, entity:block, entity:block_content_type, entity:block_content, entity:comment, entity:comment_type, entity:config_pages_type, entity:config_pages, entity:contact_form, entity:contact_message, entity:editor, entity:field_config, entity:field_storage_config, entity:file, entity:filter_format, entity:flagging, entity:flag, entity:google_api_service_client, entity:google_api_client, entity:image_style, entity:menu_link_content, entity:node, entity:node_type, entity:page_variant, entity:page, entity:path_alias, entity:rdf_mapping, entity:rest_resource_config, entity:search_api_task, entity:search_api_server, entity:search_api_index, entity:search_api_autocomplete_search, entity:shortcut_set, entity:shortcut, entity:social_auth, entity:menu, entity:action, entity:taxonomy_term, entity:taxonomy_vocabulary, entity:tour, entity:ultimate_cron_job, entity:user, entity:user_role, entity:webform_options, entity:webform, entity:webform_submission, entity:webform_access_group, entity:webform_access_type, entity:webform_image_select_images, entity:webform_options_custom, entity:view, entity:paragraph, entity:paragraphs_type, entity:base_field_override, entity:entity_view_display, entity:entity_view_mode, entity:entity_form_mode, entity:entity_form_display, entity:date_format, user_registration in Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 53 of /home1/tourcode/public_html/''/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is looking for a plugin with empty string as a name.

I also noticed have some kind of an empty string in your path. (between public_html and web)
/home1/tourcode/public_html/''/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php

It looks like the configuration of your server has a problem.